# How to Change index value

Tags: vb.net

hello guys i have a problem with index value in my combobox i have these items 
`(A)
(B)
(C)
(D)
(E)
(F)` 
these items have index value like 0 1 2 3 4 and so on 
i want to  start index 83 84 99 45 22  ... ? 
 ComboBox1.Items.Add(line)

is there way to index start 83 84 99 45 22  ... ? 
Or any suggestion from in My.Resources.TextFile1

`(A),83
(B),84
(C),99
(D),45
(E),22
(F),10`

and so on
Items,Index 
can i do that like index=0 to 83 and 1 = 84 son on
sorry for bad english

Comment: This is one _long road_. can u please reformat the question somehow? And  just maybe make the question more clear

Comment: Sorry  I Am Not Really Good At Explaining Things

Comment: The index values 0,1,2,3,4 are defined by the `ComboBox` itself to maintain its order. If you fill combobox like `B`, `A`, `C` and so on.. `B` would get index value `0`. you **can't** change the index values to 83, 84 or apple, mango etc. Hope you got the point

Comment: Instead you can use `DisplayMember` & `ValueMember` of combobox to get your need fulfilled. May I know the datasource of the combobox, and also is it winforms or wpf?

Comment: maybe you could use a Dictionary? have the the key as the index value and the value as the value of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but from what I can gather you want to add `"(A)", "(B)"` and so on to the combobox, but you want the combobox's index to start from numbers that you choose.
Not sure if you can do that as it's like a primary key and there to only keep things in order.
With that being said, you could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to achieve this to some extent.
Here is how I would do it, think of the `key` as the index value

```
Public Class Form1
Dim items As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) ''your items Dictinary List
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ''add items here.
    items.Add(83, "(A)")
    items.Add(84, "(B)")
    items.Add(99, "(C)")
    items.Add(45, "(D)")
    items.Add(22, "(E)")
    items.Add(10, "(F)")

    For Each item As String In items.Keys ''add the items key or value to the list.
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = items.Values(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex) ''we can select the value or key based on the items key or value that is allocated to it depending on which way you do it
End Sub
End Class
```

So now if you select an item from the combobox, the label will display the 'key' of the value that is selected.

Comment: Thanks for reply i understand  now i can not change  index values to 83, 84 85 but i make new way to solve this problem (lengthy but fine by me)
Again thanks for reply